# how to rewrite non exist url to display content of dynamic page from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

in wordpress normally if click domain.com/index.php?p=2
it redirect to domain.com/sample-page/

say now i like to show sample-page content domain.com/sample-page/

from non exist url

domain.com/member/abc/

domain.com/member/bbb/

domain.com/member/ccc/

but when user run any of above URL example.com/member/xxx/ in browser it will show content of example.com/sample-page/
without any redirection to example.com/sample-page/

so the address still remain in example.com/member/xxx/

please advice how to do in .htaccess or in functions.php

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess Rules file in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds pretty straight forward, all you need is a single internal rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?member/.+/?$ /sample-page/ [END]
```

Such rule has to be implemented to be applied *prior* to the wordpress internal rules.